# Google in app purchases, save consumable items data. Best practice

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I already implement Google In-app purchases successfully in my app, but i have few questions how to store consumable item data in proper way. For now when customer buy consumable item for examle 7 health point i save this data to the server via REST service. Also i use this approach to restore consumable data of the in app purchases. For non consumable i use "queryPurchases". Should i use some options that are in Google billing Api? Witch option will be the most secure and commonly used?

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view firstly for saving of the consumable data is preferably to use server to restoring amount of the purchases items. For non consumable items there is no need, because Google API gives opportunity to store this information in google account where you can cheek this programmatically.